# TultebotCable + Kinect Ports

Tags: usb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
how to create USB0 , USB1 in filesystem/dev/tty

for using 2 USB ports

one for turtlebot cable and another for Kinect .
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57554/tultebotcable-+-kinect-ports/) by [howyda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3699/howyda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Kinect is no serial device and will therefore not be mounted as ttyUSBx
Use openni_launch to access the kinect

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [howyda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3699/howyda/) on 2013-03-10**:
pls, check this question :
http://answers.ros.org/question/57553/unable-to-check-turtlebot-cable/